# How I can update the property value "position: '' ; " using webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('myclass or id')

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using webdriver to screenshot an entire page, but when scrolling down the page, I can't removed the navigation toolbar and so it will also be captured and have a problem when I am combining the images.

I am using chromedriver.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css.id.class')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style='position: none;'", element)
```

I just want to remove the header while scrolling down the page, but if there are still better capturing the whole page of a website, it will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you manually trying to scroll, to my knowledge, selenium takes the screenshot of the entire page at once?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have syntax error

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.position = 'none';", element)
```

Second, position property has no option "none". Try

```
style.display = 'none';"
```

instead

Comment: This one doesn't work too, I found out that you need to place a tag before the id when using find_element_by_css_selector('tag.id/class'). But I am now using this one and it works well for me 

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//nav[@id="cb-nav-bar"]/div')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('id', '')", element)